# libcurl post - underscore replaced with space (ubuntu)

Tags: c++, express, curl

I'm trying to send email and password in a post request to my express nodejs server using curl c++. The post data has '_' changed to ' ' when I log it from server.

```
    char emailtext[50];
    char passwordtext[50];
    int emailstrlen = wcstombs(emailtext, email->getText(), 50);
    int passwordstrlen = wcstombs(passwordtext, password->getText(), 50);
    long totalsize = emailstrlen + passwordstrlen;
    strcat(emailtext, ":");
    strcat(emailtext, passwordtext);
    // "myemail@yahoo.com:mypassword\0"
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURLcode res;
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://localhost:3000/login");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    cout << emailtext << endl;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, emailtext);
    /* pass our list of custom made headers */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_perform(curl); /* post away! */ 
    curl_slist_free_all(headers); /* free the header list */
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return true;
```

express nodejs server:

```
    app.post('/login', bodyParser.text(), function (req, res) {
         console.log("we got the post request for /login");
         console.log("logging the body!");
         console.log(req.body);
         res.header('Content-type', 'text/plain');
         return res.end('<h1>Hello, Secure World!</h1>');
    });
```

say char* emailtext = "cool_stewj@yahoo.com:lololol"

output from log on server will then be "cool stewj@yahoo.com:lololol"

What's happening? I've tried url encoding the data which turned out to be silly and pointless. How do I get that underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal in ubuntu apparently doesn't show underscores, so any log output will have underscores replaced with spaces.

Btw that's a bad example of string code in beginning. Possible to just use one buffer. Just pointing it out.

Comment: Probably should use the curl return code to do error checking too.